# Are latitude and longitude of WGS84 geodetic or geocentric?

Tags: latitude-longitude, wgs84, epsg

I note from [wiki](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System) that there are other CRS under WGS84 apart from EPSG:4326 but I am only interested in EPSG:4326.

I have also visited https://epsg.io/ page regarding [EPSG:4326](https://epsg.io/4326); however, I can’t find the keywords to solve my question. Can someone shed some lights on my problem?

Comment: [geocentricity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geocentric_model) has to do with astronomical considerations, but by no means with geodesy.

Comment: Definitive registry for EPSG is epsg.org, not epsg.io

Answer (score 2):

Latitude and longitude are by definition geodetic. Latitude and longitude in WGS84 refer to the ellipsoid compatible with ITRS. This ellipsoid is earth-centered base on the mass center of the Earth.

Comment: So Latitude and longitude in WGS84 are geodetic? I always thought they were measured from the centre.  I remember from my middle school textbook that they were measured from the centre.

Comment: @user2720402 middle school textbook tend to simplify thing, I wouldn't use them as reference on technical matter...